# Is there an optimised way to calculate `x^T A x` for symmetric `A` in Eigen++?

Tags: matrix, vector, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigen3

Given a symmetric matrix `A` and a vector `x`, I often need to calculate `x^T * A  * x`. I can do it Eigen++ 3.x with `x.transpose() * (A * x)`, but that doesn't exploit the information that `x` is the same on both sides and `A` is symmetric. Is there a more efficient way to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small matrices, writing the for loop myself seems to be faster than relying on Eigen's code. For large matrices I got good results using `.selfAdjointView`:

```
double xAx_symmetric(const Eigen::MatrixXd& A, const Eigen::VectorXd& x)
{
    const auto dim = A.rows();
    if (dim < 15) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
            const auto x_i = x[i];
            sum += A(i, i) * x_i * x_i;
            for (Eigen::Index j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                sum += 2 * A(j, i) * x_i * x[j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        return x.transpose() * A.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>() * x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How often do you calculate this? If very often for different `x`, then it might give a bit of speed-up to compute a Cholesky or LDLT decomposition of `A` and use that the product of a triangular matrix with a vector only needs half the multiplications.

Or possibly even simpler, if you decompose `A=L+D+L.T`, where `L` is strictly lower triangular and `D` is diagonal, then

```
x.T*A*x = x.T*D*x + 2*x.T*(L*x)
```

where the first terms is the sum over `d[k]*x[k]**2`. The second term, if carefully using the triangular structure, uses half the operations of the original expression.

If the triangular matrix-vector product has to be implemented outside of `Eigen` procedures, this might destroy the efficiency/optimizations of BLAS-like block operations in the generic matrix-vector product. In the end, there might be no improvements from this reduction in the count of arithmetic operations.

Comment: My use case is that `A` and `x` change together.

Comment: Would this be useful? https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1TriangularView.html

Comment: I think the way to let Eigen know "hey, this matrix is symmetric" is by using this: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointView.html